# Animate static SVG file with react-native-svg

Tags: javascript, react-native, animation, svg, react-native-svg

I'm struggling to get `react-native-svg` animate in React Native. I also tried the method they suggest with `react-native-svg-transformation` but it didn't suit my case since I'm working with many files and render them dynamically. 
Here's my render file:

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";
import { SvgXml } from "react-native-svg";
import SvgAssets from "../resources/SvgAssets";
import AssetsHelper from "../common/AssetsHelper";

class ChineseCharacter extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      xmlData: "",
    };
  }

  render() {
    const { xmlData, file } = this.state;
    if (xmlData.length === 0) {
      return <View />;
    }

    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <SvgXml xml={xmlData} width="200" height="200" />
      </View>
    );
  }

  componentDidMount(): void {
    const { character } = this.props;
    const characterUnicode = character.charCodeAt(0);
    const file = SvgAssets[characterUnicode.toString()];
    AssetsHelper(file)
      .then(result => {
        this.setState({
          xmlData: result,
        });
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }
}

export default ChineseCharacter;
```

`AssetsHelper` is basically reading the svg file and convert them to string in order to pass to `SvgXml`.
`SvgAssets` is an object with key as the charCode and value is the file, something like this:

```
const assets = {
  "11904": require("./svgs/11904.svg"),
  ...
}
```

Thank in advance.

Comment: Where can I find info about the "method they suggest with react-native-svg-transformation"?

Answer (score 1):

After few struggling hours, I have found a work around for this problem. I don't use `react-native-svg` anymore, instead I parse the .svg file to string and put it in `react-native-webview`. Work like a charm!

```
render() {
    // @ts-ignore
    const { xmlData, file } = this.state;
    if (xmlData.length === 0) {
      return <View />;
    }
    return (
      <View style={{ width: 300, height: 300 }}>
        <WebView
          source={{ html: xmlData }}
          style={{ backgroundColor: "transparent", width: 300, height: 300 }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to import the `svg` files inside `ChineseCharacter` class.

```js
import svgXml11904 from './svgs/11904.svg'

const assets = {
  "11904": svgXml11904,
  ...
}
```

Comment: I'm working with about 9000 svg files so your solution may be undoable. Thanks anyway!

Comment: You already have a file from `SvgAssets`. Why do you need `AssetsHelper`? `SvgXml` does not work with a string :)